# Read line from file then delete

Tags: bash, files, read

How can I read a series of lines from a file and then remove each line?

Obviously I can read like this:

```
while read -r line; do
echo $line
done < myfile.txt
```

But if I do this:

```
while read -r line; do
echo $line
sed '1d' myfile.txt
done < myfile.txt
```

I only get the very first line

I'm looking for an elegant way to read a line, do something with it and then remove it before moving on to the next line in the file.

Comment: Are you trying to make the program [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29)? If so, you probably want to instead write *the last processed line number* to a state file for every line. Much faster, and just as safe.

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer to invoke `sed` just one time then on each line iteration. If you like to change original file you can add **-i**(**--in-place**) option to `sed`.

```
unset n
while read -r line; do
  echo $line
  : $((n++))
done < myfile.txt
sed "1,$n d" myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sed -n '$d;w file2' >file1 <<IN
$(cat file1; echo .)
IN
```

Which will safely write every line from file1 into file2 while simultaneously deleting every line in file1. The shell handles the intermediate temp file securely - it creates one and then deletes it from its filesystem before ever writing a single byte to it.

As soon as `sed` releases the file-descriptor *(at EOF or when it terminates - whichever comes first)* the file ceases to exist at all. Unlike the common `sed -i` option, this does not depend on `sed` cleaning up after itself *(which may not happen if its processing is unexpectedly interrupted)* and nor does it carry with it the same permissions inconsistencies the `-i` option implies.

And the application need not be global as demonstrated - the lines can be either deleted from the original and/or written to the separate output selectively...

```
sed -n '$d;/pattern1/w file2
           /pattern2/p' >file1 <<IN
$(cat file1; echo .)
IN
```

...demonstrates how only lines from file1 which match `/pattern2/` will be printed back into file1 and only lines from same which match `/pattern1/` are `w`ritten to file2. Any other `sed` command is of course applicable as well.

It is probably worth noting, though, that for most shells this will not carry over NUL bytes from file1 *(which isn't often a concern for `sed` work)* - though such a thing is possible with `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace every line of a file once it was processed correctly with this snippet (do not remove if processing fails, so you can reprocess them if you need it):

```
while read; do
  if some_command_worked_correctly; then
    sed -i '1,1 d' file-to-read
  fi
done < file-to-read
```

Comment: This does not work as intended; it only deletes the first line of the file, regardless of the current line of the `read` loop.