# Shell *for* loop through file and for each line use sed to delete lines from other file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, zsh

I'm trying to clean up `long-cluttered-filename.txt` by deleting the lines that match the strings in my `delete-these-lines.txt`...

```
$ cat delete-these-lines.txt
context
platform
server
civicrm
site_enabled
client
redirection
cron_key
^\s*[0-9]*\s
alias
profile
install
ssl_
address
```

...and with a simple `for` loop I can iterate through the lines of that file like so:

```
$ for l in delete-these-lines.txt; do cat $l; done
context
platform
server
civicrm
site_enabled
client
redirection
cron_key
^\s*[0-9]*\s
alias
profile
install
ssl_
address
```

but when I try to substitute `cat` for `sed` it doesn't work.  Neither of these work:

```
for l in delete-these-lines.txt; do sed -i "/$l/d" long-cluttered-filename.txt; done
for l in delete-these-lines.txt; do sed -i '/"$l"/d' long-cluttered-filename.txt; done
```

Is this a problem with the `$l` variable being interpolated?  Is this a limitation of `for` loops?

I see answers like [loop sed to delete line with strings provided in a list of strings from a text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400867/115900) and [Read line from file then delete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180619/115900) that use `while` loops with `read` but I'd prefer to use a `for` loop if it's possible, and if it's not possible I'd like to know why.

Comment: `for l in delete-these-lines.txt ... ` loops over the file*name*, once. You presumably want `for l in $(<delete-these-lines.txt) ... ` or `for l in $(cat delete-these-lines.txt) ... ` to loop over the file's contents. But it's a **bad idea**.

Comment: can you explain why that's a bad idea?

Comment: OK perhaps I shouldn't have said "bad idea" - it's just hard to see why you are so determined to use a `for` loop in this context.

Comment: Does `delete-these-lines.txt` contain _patterns_ or _strings_?  That is, should `^\s*[0-9]*\s` match that string literally, or is that a PCRE regular expression?

Comment: @Kusalananda `^\s*[0-9]*\s` is a regex pattern (I'm not sure about PCRE though), not a literal string.

Comment: @steeldriver when you say "bad idea" are you thinking something along the lines of [using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)?  I'm not as determined to "use" a `for` loop as I am to figure out if and how it's possible; the `grep -v -f....` option looks great in how it functions, but I'm trying learn about how these loops work... and your comment on the distinction between looping over the *filename* vs the *file contents* was helpful :)

Comment: I was thinking more specifically about the issue of *word splitting*, as described here [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file) and explored more generically in [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). If you can guarantee that your lines contain no whitespace, you may not care.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two files where one contains list of strings to delete from another one, you can do the entire thing with one simple `grep`:

```
grep -v -f delete-these-lines.txt long-cluttered-filename.txt
```

This will output all the strings from `long-cluttered-filename.txt` which do not match to patterns from `delete-these-lines.txt`.

Note, that in case some string in `long-cluttered-filename.txt` will contain `client` (e.g. `123superclient456`) it still matches to `client` and will be excluded from the output.

Answer (score 1):

Never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code. What you want to do is a bad idea as you already know, but see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for how to read lines from a file in shell and then you'd write it as:

```
while IFS= read -r regexp; do
    sed -i "/$regexp/d" long-cluttered-filename.txt
done < delete-these-lines.txt
```

but again - don't do it for all the reasons you've already been warned of (plus you're just re-implementing `grep -v -f delete-these-lines.txt long-cluttered-filename.txt > tmp && mv tmp long-cluttered-filename.txt` less efficiently, less robustly, and less portably).